# How to wire this old Lennox thermostat to my Heil 2003 furnace?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

Here is my attempt which isn't working. Maybe I should jumper R to G and move the green wire to C with Blue? The wires I cut off it had that jumpered.

Here is the image address: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkBZB.jpg
Sorry, don't know how to use the image button.

Comment: Can you post a link to the manual for your furnace please, or at least a model number?

Comment: Its a International Comfort Products made in Jun 2006 Model HM8F (maybe P) NO7 5B12B1

Heres a pic: <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/ivRLQp7"><a href="//imgur.com/a/ivRLQp7"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


Here's a pic of Lennox Tstat:https://i.imgur.com/tjprnWI.png

Comment: Its a International Comfort Products made in Jun 2006 Model HM8F (maybe P) NO7 5B12B1

Heres a pic: https://i.imgur.com/n3a9uOM.png


Here's a pic of Lennox Tstat:https://i.imgur.com/tjprnWI.png

Comment: Here's the furnace connections: https://i.imgur.com/Raf882n.png